# How to export data to different excel sheets in python pandas?

Tags: pandas

How can i export data to different excel sheets in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile('my_excel.xlsx')

new_sheet1 = calculated_df.to_excel('my_excel.xlsx', 'sheet1')
new_sheet2 = calculated_df2.to_excel('my_excel.xlsx', 'sheet2')
```

When i use above code, the `sheet2` overwrite the `sheet1`, how can i export to different excel tabs?

Thank you!

Export data to different excel tabs via Pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) :

```
list_df = [calculated_df, calculated_d2]

with pd.ExcelWriter("my_excel.xlsx") as writer:
    for idx, df in enumerate(list_df, start=1):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"sheet{idx}", index=False)
```

Comment: thank you, i tried the code and it errors out for me:      

NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.

Comment: You haven't shared an example of your dataframes but it seems like at least one of your dataframes has a MultiIndex. Have you tried with `index=True` ?

Comment: index=True works! thanks so much!